# Unity WebGL build, how to set canvas size for mobile browsers?

Tags: html, css, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have an android smartphone with a FullHD screen (1920*1080). And I am building a game with Default Canvas settings: 1280*720. And in my html template I've set canvas size:

```
<div id="gameContainer" style="width: 1280px; height: 720px; margin: auto"></div>
```

But when I run the game in landscape orientation on my smartphone, it can't fit to the screen, it is too big! Why? 
It supposed to be smaller then 1080p browser screen. Also, in portrait mode everything is fine and game's window is scaled properly to fit the screen.

I've tried to use meta viewport tag. With it I've managed to fit the canvas to the screen, but it had broken everything else.

Unity version is 2018.2.7. Mobile browser is Chrome for Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can edit your gameContainer div to fill the tab, so it is full in whatever resolution, even when resolution changes:

```
<div id="gameContainer" style="padding: 0px; position: absolute; height:100vh; width:100vw;"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Now, my gameContainer and #canvas elements are somehow scaled to the mobile screen size in landscape orientation. I can play in lanscape.

Comment: But it is not fulling in when I am running the game in portrait orientation. In landscape mode it is trying to fit screen width, but in portrait - screen height, so, only the center is visible.